# Why doesn't Google Chrome on Mac pick up local Certificate Authority as the other browsers?

Tags: ssl-certificate, mac-osx, certificate-authority, google-chrome, ssl-certificate-errors

I have generated local CA and Cert on my Mac, from this walkthrough: https://blog.arrogantrabbit.com/ssl/Root-CA-macOS/

I then provide the certificate/key to nginx local server, that I visit with my local browser, using a domain included in the cert.

It works in Safari and Firefox, that both display a valid certificate, **but not Chrome, I am wondering why?**

*Note: I first made a mistake and created a certificate with SAN hostnames separated by comma instead of spaces. I then replaced the bogus certificate by a good one. Could that be the cause of the issue? I would say no because Chrome is complaining about the CA, not the Cert, but I wanted to mention it nonetheless.*

Here are some screenshot of Chrome (err):

[image: Chrome CA Error]

and Safari with CA details:

[image: Safari Warking CA details]

Comment: AFAIK Chrome transitioned from using the system CA certificates first to relying (only/first) on the CA certficates in its own CA "Root Store" https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy/ You might see something more in the chrome security settings `chrome://settings` and when you access  the `manage device settings` tab and  can you access your "keychain" and confirm that your custom CA is in the certificates tab?

Comment: Yes, when I click in that section, it says `Chrome will add custom root certificates from the certificates used by your computer’s operating system. To review the certificates on your device:`. When clicking to see managed certificates, it opens Keychain Access, and I see my generated Root CA, and it is trusted by Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the issue and ended up regenerating a new CA and Cert